# Is anyone really using git super/subprojects?

Tags: git

Is anyone using the new git super/subproject feature in real projects? How well does it work? For instance, I understand that if I push to a subproject I have to manually call superprojects hooks (maybe using the subprojects hook, but nevertheless)?

Comment: Is a subproject the same as a submodule? I've used those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using submodule, you are defining in your Git workspace (meaning your "super-project" Git repository) a **configuration**.
By "configuration", I mean "the list of tags or SHA-1 node necessary to work in your workspace".
(and by work, I mean whatever "development effort" you are doing within your workspace: classic compilation, or patch, or merge, or deployment, or...).
That is the case when your are cloning a super-project and "`git update`" your submodules: you are checkouting the exact repos SHA1 which were previously committed in the super-project (recorded as **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** in [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309)).

The other mode is when you are working on your super-project *and* on one or more submodules.
That means, for a given submodules, you have checked out a specific branch (you are no longer using a detached HEAD for the content of that submodules, but rather a pointer to the tip of a branch).
Then, "pushing a submodule" means updating a distant repository containing that sub-module (and only that one).

The actual trick in that last scenario (which could deserve a hook of you want one) is when you are pushing the super-project: you need to be sure to have pushed all your sub-modules first.

From the [submodule tutorial](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial):

> Always publish the submodule change before publishing the change to the superproject that references it. If you forget to publish the submodule change, others won't be able to clone the repository (of the super-project)

Don't forget you [can configure a submodule to follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

Comment: This sounds like an alpha version of submodules, too many complications... :S

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, we are trying to make the leap to git, and our project ([bitweaver](http://www.bitweaver.org/), a content management system) is a highly modular system, with [nearly 160 repositories](http://github.com/bitweaver/)). A "build" generally contains two dozen or more sub-repositories. We used 'virtual modules' in CVS, and this worked fantastically for us, however CVS has it's own limitations for staging commits.

Git submodules have some severe limitations, and you should definitely evaluate mercurial's implementation as it is a certainly more friendly and flexible for external/modular projects (ie it supports other VCS systems, even HgGit).

Here are the biggest challenges:

1. Each submodule is hard linked to a
   particular commit when you "git submodule add" in the super-respository. This is by
   design, and sought as a benefit by
   git maintainers, so I would not expect it to change any time soon. This is painful in
   a system like ours where commit's
   are always happening in the
   submodules. You have to update the
   super project to keep up, or update
   your sub-repos to master after
   initial submodule update. (see
   supergit below for our solution).
2. You cannot easily commit and push to
   all the sub-repo's from the root.
   This is also very annoying, see
   supergit below.
3. Various [gotchas](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Gotchas) that can be excruciating, especially things that "silently overwrite changes".

**supergit**

We've written a [shell script call supergit](http://gist.github.com/463628) that handles some of the painfulness. It does the clone, submodule init, update, and checkout master all in one fell swoop. It will also perform git commands to all directories in the super-repo individually (bulk git processing of sorts).

HTH, good luck.

Comment: +1 this is a good overview of the pros and cons. FYI, for the hard-coded commits, this is expected to be useful in cases where submodules are rarely (or manually) updated to known, good versions (eg. production tags) -- so it works very well in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean submodules, then certainly.

The submodules don't and should not know everywhere they're used.  For example, I have one submodule that is used in several projects that I know of (and quite possibly several that I don't).

Pushing to a submodule does not in any way affect the version of code used by the project containing the submodule, so I'm not sure what you'd want a hook to do anyway.

Comment: If, for instance, the submodule is just part of a larger sw I might want to compile the entire package when someone does a push.

Comment: You're missing both points.  1) Changing the submodule does not change any project containing it.  At all.  A new build would be identical to the previous build.  2) A given submodule may be used by thousands of applications and can't know what they all are.

Comment: Of course the module might be used by different applications but of course the main project would have the build script that includes the module. 

I don't understand this "at all" thing - if I have a project with two submodules and someone pushes their changes to one of the submodules how come the submodule doesn't change? If it changes and I have a build script that includes that submodule, then of course the build is different.

Comment: No, it is not different.  The super project references an *exact version* of the code within the submodule.  Changing the underlying code doesn't create instability in projects that use it.  If you want the super project to change, you have to tell the super project to use a newer version of the submodule -- at which point it's a super project change and that projects hooks will fire as usual.