# Git won't let me merge

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging, git-merge

Good evening!

I know this is very usual and there are probably thousands of answers on the internet but I couldn't find one that was helfull.

I have two local branches:

> - MASTER
> - Mk

I made a lot of changes to Mk, committed these, and switched to MASTER to merge these two branches. But there were conflicts. So now I am on the MASTER branch, can not switch to Mk anymore, but need to override my MASTER with Mk.

It keeps saying

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Is there a way to do this?

```
 git mergetool --tool=meld    #No files need merging
 git merge -s theirs Mk       #Could not find merge strategy 'theirs'.
 git merge -X recursive=theirs Mk   # error: Your local changes to the following files
```

would be overwritten by merge

and I did not push my changes to my online repository yet.

I can see the commit with all the changes but can not access its code.

Just started using git some time ago but never ran into troubles like 
that before. I would really appreciate any help I can get :s

Comment: Is git waiting for you to resolve merge conflicts? What does `git status` say?

Comment: If you're willing to nuke your worktree you can `git  checkout -f Mk`.

Comment: @Steinar Yes I think it does.. I get a lot of modified files that do not seem to be modified at all. git diff prints all the files with "old mode 100644 new mode 100755"... I have lost every orientation whatsoever

Comment: @jthill Thanks! This is a great way to secure your code if you have to!

Answer (score 8):

Since there isn't a [`--theirs` strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2303198/6309) (even though there are [ways to simulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)), couldn't you:

- merge first master to mk: `git checkout mk && git merge -s ours master`
- the merge mk to master (fast-forward): `git checkout master && git merge mk`

The `-s ours` strategy will make sure you keep `mk` version in case of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and references! I'll take a deep look at it. I can't checkout mk because of the error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout.

Comment: @MichaelKargl if you have local changes, stash them first (git stash: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: this is BS. `git help merge` lists `theirs` as a strategy being "opposite of 'ours'"

Comment: @steve but it *is not* a merge strategy: '`ours`' and '`theirs`' are listed as **parameter of the '`recursive`' merge strategy**. With the caveat: "This should not be confused with the `ours` merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it". There is indeed a separate '`ours`' merge strategy. But as far as I know, there is no '`theirs`' merge strategy.

Comment: Sorry I guess I was just mad at the naming choices in git itself.  I've since figured out an approach I prefer, which is rather simple and I have [shared below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601842/git-wont-let-me-merge/18155444#18155444). Not sure why I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure, you are on a clean working copy of MASTER.

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs Mk
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how but the file permissions got changed for some files of the master branch.

git diff:

```
diff --git a/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig b/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

I committed the changes made:

```
git commit --all -m "changes permissions from 644 to 755"
```

After that I was able to merge the branch as if nothing ever happened

```
git merge Mk
```

Although I know this is not the most elegant solution.. But I am glad to have my code back! Now I only have to figure out how to reverse this permission change. Thanks for the great help though!

Comment: Interesting feedback. +1 A better ft for your particular situation than my answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

> > error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

This is typically because you have *uncommitted* changes that would be overwritten.  So first you need to deal with that by either (1) committing or (2) stashing:

```
git add .; git commit -m "committing my workz"
# or
git add.; git stash
```

Now try the merge.  Maybe you have conflicts.  You want all the changes from `mk` to take precedence over whatever is in `master`, because git is a little too sensitive about detecting conflicts sometimes (eg, no real conflicts), or because whomever was committing to `master` was a dunce:

```
git checkout master
git merge mk
# oh noes! merge conflicts
# CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo_bar.txt
git checkout mk -- foo_bar.txt
git commit
```

BOOM!  Screw `master`. You ain't my master.

Note: `git checkout` is normally used to repoint `HEAD` (and update your working directory) to a branch/tag/SHA/whatever, but if you do `git checkout SHA -- file` it won't repoint your `HEAD`, instead it will update the file you pass after the `--` to reflect that file/path content in the SHA you pass. You can pass a path instead of exact file and it will checkout all files that are different in that path.