# Can't merge branches Xcode Sourcecontrol

Tags: xcode, git, merge

For some reason Xcode won't let me merge my development branch with the master branch. The merge button is faded out like so:

[image]

And some of the files has this red indicator:

[image]

What can I do this fix this, and merge my development branch with my master branch?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Click on the conflicted files and choose merge type.

Comment: @Seya, In Xcode 6.2, I clicked on the conflicted file, and I don't see any *merge type*.  Don't do what I did: I figured the master branch got changed somehow when I was on another branch.  The other branch worked, and it was the code I wanted to save.  So, I committed the other branch, then switched to the master branch, then *discarded all changes*.  Then I switched to the other branch, merged into the master branch, and...nothing works.  It's a fairly simple app, yet I cannot figure out why it won't work.  git is such a pleasure to work with!

Comment: For anyone that finds their way here, you'll have to use git on the command line to solve things, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601842/git-wont-let-me-merge

Answer (score 0):

Click on the file that has the conflict symbol "C", then you can see which lines are in conflict, just click on the conflict, in the middle of the screen, on the bottom of the screen you will see the merge type.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnWeu.png)

The image self explanatory, so you will see which merge type best server for you!