# git merge branch overwriting destination

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-merge

My repository have a **`master`** and **`dev`** branch.

At this time I wish merge the **`dev`** with the **`master`**, or better, not a merge, but *total replacement the content* of the **`master`** branch with the **`dev`**.

Is it possible, and how you would do it with git commands?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, and for the two vote for closing that question as off topic. Don't worry: it is perfectly on topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a "merge" with a "theirs" strategy, which [doesn't exist natively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2303198/6309).

But you can simulate it through a number a way, as in "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/6309)"

The one I like is through the creation of an extra branch:

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b tmp
git merge -s ours master         # ignoring all changes from master
git checkout master
git merge tmp                    # fast-forward master to tmp HEAD
git branch -D tmp
```

Comment: thanks, and this I need to do starting from my **dev** branch right?

Comment: @ghiboz yes. I have edited the answer. Do it on a clone for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you started with `master`...and sometime later you created a `dev` branch (from `master` **`HEAD`** or some *previous commit* of `master`).
You can also do the following.

```
# find common ancestor

git merge-base master dev

# This will give you SHA-1 of ancestor like this: `4de51ba41fba357ac9ce63f098451cd1fc2dacbe`
# A hard reset master to this commit
git checkout master

git reset --hard 4de51ba41f

git rebase master dev

# After successful completion you will find yourself checked out on `dev`
# checkout master again and merge dev to get your final result

git checkout master

git merge dev

# Now your master will be same as dev
```