# How to force update when doing git pull?

Tags: git

I'm doing git pull of an open source lib, I don't care what my local copy is I just want to update it with the origin's version.

i.e. it can blow away my local changes.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

Comment: And if you've created any local commits that you want to throw away, use: `git reset --hard origin/master` instead.

Comment: And if you don't have custom local changes, you might want to do `git pull --rebase`

Comment: doesn't work for me getting CONFLICTS and auto-merge fail messages. I don't care I just want to completely overwrite everything...

Comment: @schwiz You can delete the branch, or rename it, and recreate it to track from origin:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665045/can-i-tell-git-pull-to-overwrite-instead-of-merge

Comment: This answer assumes that you have never made any commits to your branch, pretty far from what the question said ("I don't care what my local copy is").

Answer (score 39):

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/name_of_branch  # correct state but in 'head without a name'
git checkout -B name_of_branch      # overwrite current tree onto name_of_branch
```

This checks out the remote tracking branch into a head without a name, then you can have a look and check you're happy. Whenever you want to (even after changes or commits) the second git checkout labels your current tree with 'name_of_branch', even if it has to delete the old name_of_branch to do so.

---

### Edit: 'What a crazy command line syntax'

The syntax of git commands seems unintuitive. In fact it's the Git data model that is unintuitive. This isn't bad design, but because it works with files, branches, commits in ways that are much more flexible and powerful than other version control systems. Once you grok how these things work in Git, the command line will make a lot of sense and you will be able to accurately guess how to do complicated things.

- `git fetch`
  This **fetches** all the updates that have happened on the `origin` server since the last time. **Git separates fetching from the server from updating, merging, etc. any of your branches**. All the branches called `origin/XXX` are *your* most recent versions of what's on the server. They are not *remote branches* but *remote tracking branches*, local branches which track remote branches. When you do `git fetch`, you update them, without touching any of your own branches. When you do `git merge`, `git rebase`, and so on, you use the fetched version, *without* grabbing a more recent copy from the server. This means you have control over when network requests are made (if you aren't always connected to the server), and you can 'fetch' a snapshot of the server, then merge at your leisure. **If in doubt, do `git fetch` first.**
- `git checkout origin/name_of_branch`
  `git checkout` does two things. It updates your files to that branch, and it sets your `HEAD` to that branch. The files things is what you'd expect. The `HEAD` things means that when you do commits, they will added to the end of the branch that `HEAD` points to. IOW, `checkout` does both *output* - write the right versions of the files, and prepares for *input* - gets ready to store the commits you are going to do in the right place. If you checkout a branch called `foo`, your tree changes to the state saved in `foo`, **and** the next commits you do will be added to `foo`. In the case of `origin\xyz`, you can't write your changes to an `origin` branch - these track what is on the `origin` server and can't be committed to directly. So the checkout updates the files, and sets `HEAD` to nothing - an unnamed branch. This stops you accidentally committing your newly checked out stuff back onto the previous branch you were using, and in fact you will be heavily discouraged by git from committing at all until you have a destination branch.
- `git checkout -B name_of_branch`
  As usual, **when git does two different things with one command, both of them can be configured separately**. So the second part of what `checkout` does, setting `HEAD` to the branch you want to commit to, can be to a new branch, instead of the branch you're checking out, if you use the `-B` option. So `git checkout -B new_stuff old_stuff` will set all your files to the state in `old_stuff`, but get you ready to write your commits to the new branch `new_stuff`. This is a common task, and saves you checking out a branch then forking it, in two steps. Now, **almost all arguments to git commands can be omitted, and git will do the most obvious thing**. In this case, that is making a new branch *based on the one you are on*, rather than one you want to checkout. So git takes the unnamed branch you are on, and makes a new branch called `name_of_branch`, which you can start committing to.
  Note that an uppper case letter "B" kind of means 'force'. If you used "-b" git would refuse to overwrite an already existing branch. With "-B" it will go ahead and do it without warning or confirming.

Comment: @cept0 if you read only several hundred words of heavily bulleted and bolded explanation, you too could learn to love git command syntax!

Answer (score 21):

The go-to, *knee-jerk*, solution is: `git reset --hard origin/master` †

† or `origin/main` or whatever the name of your origin's branch is.

It's the almighty solution for experts and beginners alike that swiftly gets the job done.  ***Albeit while blowing away all uncommitted changes without warning.***

The **safer** command is slightly more of a pain to type: `git checkout -B master origin/master`

#### Enter aliases:

```
git config --global alias.become '!git checkout -B "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"'
```

Henceforth, one can type: `git become origin/master`

Comment: `origin/master` gives error message. `origin/main` works. Additionally the folders and files have current date/time, not the date/time in the repo.

Comment: Updated to clarify branch name.  The thing about date/time sounds like a bad expectation as git doesn't record timestamps of files or folders.

Comment: I beg to differ on the timestamps. Git tells you how many minutes, hours, days, months or years ago a file was last changed. That is only possible with a timestamp on each file.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That info in visualizations such as in GitHub is based on the timestamp of the commit.  It's not the timestamp of the file.  Git [isn't concerned about file-system timestamps](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F) and neither records or makes attempts to restore said timestamps when checking out files.