# git with XCode and ignoring .xcodeproj on merge?

Tags: xcode, git

I'm getting up to speed on using git with XCode but have run into a situation that I'm not quite sure how to handle.

I have a branch of my project "`branchA`" that has a build target base SDK of iOS 3.2

I have "`branchB`" that has been forked from branchA that has a build target base SDK for iOS4.2

I'm continuing with development on both branches, `branchA` with functionality that doesn't depend on SDK4.2 features, `branchB` for those features that do depend on 4.2

From time to time, I want to merge the changes made in `branchA` into `branchB`.
This of course results in some conflicts that I can easily correct -- except those that occur in the `.xcodeproj` file

How can I tell git not to merge the `.xcodeproj` file from `branchA` into `branchB` -- in essence, keep the `.xcodproj` file in branchB and ignore any differences it may have with `branchA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I detail in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544672/git-strategy-to-have-a-set-of-commits-limited-to-a-particular-branch/2544893#2544893), you can use

- a [merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist/1910479#1910479) with a [keepmine script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp).
- or a [git rerere](http://www.ru.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) to record one merge resolution and keep re-applying it.

Comment: Awesome -- thanks very much!   I'm assuming that wildcard chars are valid in the .gitattributes file?  i.e. If I want to 'keepMine' for all files in the .xcodeproj directory, I can use '* merge keepMine' ? (quotes added for demarcation only).   Doing so appears to work as I expect, but I'm not familiar enough with the .gitattributes file.

Comment: I think I found my answer regarding using * in the .gitattributes  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist/1910479#1910479  Thanks Again.