# git merge should ignore one directory

Tags: git, version-control

I have tons of data in directory called reports. While doing git merge with another branch I am getting lots of conflicts for files under reports directory. I would like git merge to ignore files under reports.

In another words I would like all the data from reports from master and not from lab branch.

Is that possible?

This is what I am doing right now.

```
git checkout master
git merge lab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need those files versioned, but keeping only the version on master branch, you need a **[merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist/1910479#1910479)**: see [here for a `keepMine` script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495).

Each time you will merge lab to master, all files within the report directory will keep their content (the one versioned on master).