# 'Ignore' binary files in git rebase 'theirs'

Tags: git, binary, rebase

I want to go from this

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G
```

where Branch1 is pointing at E and Branch2 is pointing at G

to this:

```
Branch1:    A - B - C - D - E
                     \
Branch2:              F - G
```

And I want Branch2 to always 'win', I've got as far as this:

```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs --onto C Branch1 Branch2
```

That works fine - except that rebase chokes on binary files - saying it can't merge them. How do I go about telling git that I don't want to merge them, I just want to take 'theirs' each time?

Comment: @Victor, I mean that if there are any conflicts, instead of asking me to resolve them, git will take whatever is in Branch2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go about telling git that I don't want to merge them, I just want to take 'theirs' each time?

That would be with a custom merge driver, that you can associate specifically with all binaries (`*.dll`, `*.exe`, `*.so`, ... whatever your particular binary extension is in your case)

See "[`git merge -s theirs` needed — but I know it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist/1910479#1910479)" for illustration.

What I haven't tested is: does the custom merge driver applies during a `rebase --onto`.

Comment: @VonC, one thing that's not clear to me in my scenario: where do I create the `.gitattributes` file? In commit C?

Comment: @Benjol: good question. Commit C or F, depending on that "inversion" which occurs with the rebase...

Comment: @VonC, I tried (in a test repo) on C, seems to have worked! Further question: in my case, given that I want `theirs` of everything, couldn't I just do `echo * merge=keepTheirs > .gitattributes`, and then do a straight rebase onto?

Comment: @Benjol: '*' is good for 'everything', even tough in this scenario I recently discovered the 'ours' merge strategy (which might not be useful in your specific case): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267

Comment: @VonC, yeah, ours/theirs in the context of rebase just hurts my head :(

Comment: @Benjol: I did make pretty drawings to illustrate that inversion though ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051461/git-rebase-keeping-track-of-local-and-remote/3052118#3052118

Comment: @VonC, I know, but my head still hurts :) For some reason a simple `--onto` doesn't work, but no matter, now I'm going to try on the 'real' repo.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a shot in the dark:

From the `git-rebase` documentation:

```
   -m, --merge
       Use merging strategies to rebase. When the recursive (default)
       merge strategy is used, this allows rebase to be aware of renames
       on the upstream side.

       Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the
       working branch on top of the <upstream> branch. Because of this,
       when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the
       so-far rebased series, starting with <upstream>, and theirs is the
       working branch. In other words, the sides are swapped.

   -X <strategy-option>, --strategy-option=<strategy-option>
       Pass the <strategy-option> through to the merge strategy. This
       implies --merge and, if no strategy has been specified, -s
       recursive. Note the reversal of ours and theirs as noted in above
       for the -m option.
```

If `-X` implies `--merge`, and `--merge` swaps `theirs` and `ours`, maybe that's the problem. What happens if you switch `theirs` for `ours`?

Comment: From what I have understood ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051461/git-rebase-keeping-track-of-local-and-remote)), when rebasing, 'ours' and 'theirs' get switched, so in the context of my question, ours is the branch I'm rebasing onto (Branch1), and theirs is the branch I'm rebasing (Branch2). In this case, it is actually `theirs` that I want to preserve.

Comment: Ah, okay. So I take it that part is correct then. Difficult, this one.