# Rational clear case CM API fail to checkout source code

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

I am trying to connect clear case server using Java code with help IBM ClearCase CM API.
Currently I have below setup:

1. I have clear case client (CCRC) 7.1 is install on my machine.
2. View is created with model type VOB using CCRC client.

If I try to checkout code using above Java code it showing below error:

```
CRVAP0087E (conflict): CCRC command 'checkout' failed: Unable to find VOB object
for "E:\ccweb_views\akash.sharma\akash.sharma_AR_TAS_Release1_dev\": 
not a ClearCase object 
Version discordance detected for "E:\ccweb_views\akash.sharma\akash.sharma_AR_TAS_Release1_dev\". 

ClearCase CM Server: Error: Not an object in a vob: "E:\ccweb_views\akash.sharma\akash.sharma_AR_TAS_Release1_dev\".  
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493) at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)  
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:538)  
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.Util.ccrcCmdStatusToWvcmException(Util.java:155)*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to resolve the "discordance" issue: See [technote swg21223087](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21223087).

[image: Checkout resource with discordance]

> The server and client are in disagreement about the state of the element version in question. This is known as discordance.
>
> This state can occur after you undo checkout or undo hijack on a file or directory element.
>
> Discordance will also occur in the following scenario:
>
> 1. `CCRC` client loads a file (`foo.txt`)
> 2. Native ClearCase client renames file (`foo.txt` to `FOO.TXT` changing the case ONLY) in dynamic view
> 3. `CCRC` client performs "update resources" operation
> 4. `CCRC` will see `FOO.TXT` in a discordance state

Solution ([help page](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_maintenance_discord.htm)):

> 1. Select the resources that you want to restore. You can select individual resources or an entire ClearCase view. (Restoring a resource that is not in an unknown state has no effect on the resource.)
> 2. To open the Restore Resources dialog box, take either of the following actions:
>
>    - Select **`Refresh > Repair Discordance`** from the ClearCase menu.
>    - Select **`Refresh > Repair Discordance`** from the element context menu or **`Refresh > Repair > Discordance`** from the view context menu.
> 3. Specify restore options in the dialog box and then click Apply.

Comment: could you give my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507288/ignore-binary-files-in-git-rebase-theirs) some loving attention, pretty please? :)

Comment: @Benjol: your wish is my command ;) I just hope my answer can actually help (not tested exactly in your scenario).