# How to integrate ClearCase client CCRC 7.1 with Cruise Control build integration (java)?

Tags: clearcase, cruisecontrol, clearcase-remote-client

What is needed to have a build integration (Cruise Control) on a workstation where CCRC is installed?

Answer (score 0):

The principle of a build scheduler is to trigger a build based on certain criteria: with an SCM, the criteria is typically the detection of new versions.

The local workstation cannot ake a simple 'lshistory' in the local view, because the local view isn't actually a view (it is a copy of the snapshot 'web' view which is created/maintained on the CCRC server).

The idea could be to use the [CCRC Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775665/java-clearcase-api) (as you do in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930151/rational-clear-case-cm-api-fail-to-checkout-source-code)), but in a script made to update the CCRC view and see if any new version is detected.