# How to make a recursive checkout of files & subdirectories with CCRC

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I am using following version of clearcase -
Rational ClearCase Remote Client Version: 7.1.2

In my attempt to checkout files and folders recursively, I read these links:

- [How do I perform a recursive checkout using ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577/how-do-i-perform-a-recursive-checkout-using-clearcase)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4687.html

The issue is I am not able to locate these bin files used in these articles:

1. `cleartool.exe` not located in (`c:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin\cleartool.exe`)
2. `clearmenuadmin.exe` not located in (`C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin\clearmenuadmin.exe`)

Not to mention windows search could not locate any of these files in `C:\Program Files`.
Please suggest what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use cleartool commands with CCRC, only the GUI and CCRC/Teamapi (as in "[Rational clear case CM API fail to checkout source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930151/rational-clear-case-cm-api-fail-to-checkout-source-code)").

The CCRC is a ClearCase *Remote* Client, with none of the executables of a full ClearCase client.

Maybe the simplest way is to use  Use "Environment -> ClearCase Search" GUI, to search for all elements, and select them all to checkout them.