# Why is Git saying file is 'deleted by us' when I haven't touched it?

Tags: git

I adjusted 2 files and went to merge them to Github. However, when I run a push I get an error:

```
Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#       deleted by us:   somefolder/somefile.ext
```

However, I have not touched this file. When looking at my local directory I see the file is still very much intact.

Would anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See "[Who is “us” according to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21025695/6309)"

> When you merge, `us` refers to the branch you're merging into, as opposed to them, the branch to be merged.

So the destination branch should have this file deleted.

See "[git merge “deleted by us”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746311/6309)" for resolution: you can add it back or remove it.

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016308/6309) [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016308/6309), a "us" in this situation (where you did not delete the file yourself) means a rebase (like a `git pull --rebase`).

See "[git rebase, keeping track of 'local' and 'remote'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)"

- local ("us") references the partially rebased commits: "ours" (the upstream branch)
- remote ("them") refers to the incoming changes: "theirs" - the current branch before the rebase, ie your branch where you did not delete that file.

Answer (score 5):

You said:

> I adjusted 2 files and went to merge them to Github.

This is not how Git works.  You run `git commit` to make commits *locally* (in your repository).  You run `git fetch` to obtain commits from another Git (such as one running on GitHub), which adds more commits *locally* in your repository.  Then you can merge or rebase commits *locally*.  Everything happens locally.  This really starts to matter in a moment, as we'll see.

It seems that somewhere along the way, you ran `git merge` or `git rebase`, or had some proxy command (such as `git pull`) run `git merge`  or `git rebase` for you, because:

> ... when I run a push I get an error [starting with `Unmerged paths`]

This means you have not yet *finished* the merge or rebase.  The merge-or-rebase gave you an error, telling you that one of your commit series removed a file, and the other of your commits series modified the file.

The question then becomes:

- Did you run `git merge`, or did you run `git rebase`?  This matters because the `deleted by us` claim is from a perspective that reverses when you are rebasing.
- And of course, what do you want to do to resolve this situation?

There's a sort of general problem with this whole "ours/theirs" notation, because of the fact that everything you do is local.  Even if you got some commits made by someone else, they're still *your* commits, in your repository.  You just did not make them yourself.

I strongly suspect that you ran `git rebase`, perhaps through `git pull` (which runs `git fetch` first, and then runs either `git merge` or `git rebase` according to whatever instructions you give `git pull`).

#### Why merge or rebase is required

Let's look for a moment at how merge and rebase work in the presence of new commits brought in from someone else.  We start with what you have in your repository, which is a series of commits, the last one or two or however many of them being ones *you* made.  For simplicity, let's assume you made them on your `master` branch:

```
          H--I   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
```

Here `H` and `I` are the commits you made.  The reason we drew them up on a separate line is that your Git remembers the commit that some *other* Git had as *its* master, which we're showing here as commit `G`:

```
          H--I   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- origin/master
```

Now you run `git fetch`.  This may obtain some new commit(s) from the other Git involved here.  Let's call these commits `J` and `K`, and draw them in:

```
          H--I   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--J--K   <-- origin/master
```

You now have two options for combining "your" new work (commit `H`) with "their" new work (commit `I`).  These options are `git merge` and `git rebase`.  Using merge is conceptually a bit simpler, so we will start with merge, but both wind up using what I call Git's internal *merge machinery*.

#### How merge works

Git begins by identifying the *merge base* commit.  This is the last commit that you, on your `master`, have in common with "them", on your `origin/master`.  That is, we start at the two *tip* (rightmost) commits and work backwards—leftwards—until the two graph lines meet up.  That's at commit `G`.

Next, Git effectively runs:

```
git diff G I   # figure out what "we" did on master
git diff G K   # figure out what "they" did on origin/master
```

Git then tries to *combine* the two sets of changes.  Suppose "we" changed file `README` and "they" also changed the *same* file.  But we added one new line near the top, and they removed one line near the bottom.  It's easy to combine these changes: just keep the new added line near the top, and remove the line near the bottom, from the original version of `README` in commit `G`.  That gives us the new final version, which Git will put in the new merge commit it will make.

If that were the *only* change, Git would go ahead and make the new commit, with the new version of `README`.  The commit would be a new commit, on `master`, and would look like this:

```
          H--I--L   <-- master
         /     /
...--F--G--J--K   <-- origin/master
```

But suppose that besides both "we" (commits `H--I`) and "they" (commits `J--K`) modifying `README`, we also touch one line in `somefile.ext`, and they *remove* `somefile.ext` entirely.  This is a *modify/delete conflict*: Git does not know whether to take the file from `G` and keep our change, or remove the file from `G` entirely.  Git stops, does *not* make merge commit `L`, and instead says that there is a merge conflict, with `somefile.ext` as an "unmerged path".

If we ask about the status, Git will say:

```
    deleted by them: somefile.ext
```

and this makes sense since "our" changes are commits `H--I`.  Commits `J--K` are ours too in that they are in our repository (but *we* didn't make them, we just got them from someone else).

In any case, Git leaves `somefile.ext` in our *work-tree* so that we can open the file in the editor and modify it if needed.  Then we can `git add` or `git rm` the file, whatever is appropriate.  Then we run `git commit` to finish the merge, with us figuring out what to do about the modify/delete conflict.  This will make the final merge commit `L` and we will be ready (and OK) to push.

#### Rebase is a bit more complicated but has the same problem

Now let's look at how `git rebase` works.

Git still identifies the merge base commit as before, but instead of trying to merge what we did (commits `H--I`) directly with what they did, Git tries to *copy* our changes to *new* commits.  (Git must do this copying because no commit can ever be changed.)

Git essentially does:

```
git checkout <hash-of-K>
```

followed by:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-H>
```

Let's say that in `H`, we modified `README`.  We're already sitting on commit `K`, in which "they" modified a line near the end.  In commit `H`, we modified a line near the top.  We tell Git: *Copy the other commit's modification from `H` and make a new commit that does what `H` did.*  Git *can* do this because that's just modifying an existing file in a nice safe place to do it.  Git commits the result as a copy of `H`, which we can call `H'`, and we now have:

```
          H--I   [somewhat in limbo]
         /
...--F--G--J--K   <-- origin/master
               \
                H'  <-- HEAD
```

Next, Git tries to cherry-pick commit `I`.  This is the one where we modify file `somefile.ext`.  But we're on commit `H'`, which is based on commit `K`, which *does not have* `somefile.ext`.  It's just gone!  So Git stumbles over the change and stops with a merge conflict.

Who modified file `somefile.ext`?  That's commit `I`, the other ("them") commit we are cherry-picking.  Who *removed* `somefile.ext`?  Well, that was probably commit `K` (it was `J` or `K` for sure), but as far as Git is concerned, that's *us*.  *We* removed `somefile.ext`.  So now Git says:

```
    deleted by us: somefile.ext
```

Just as before, Git stops and makes us clean up the mess.  Git doesn't know if `somefile.ext` should be modified or removed entirely, so it leaves it in the work-tree.  We must make the decision, based on our commits `J--K` and our commits `H--I`.  We edit the file and `git add` it, or `git rm` it, to finish the merge work that `git cherry-pick` could not do on its own.  This time, though, instead of `git commit`, we should run `git rebase --continue`.

Git will now try to finish the rebase, making new copy `I'` with whatever other changes we got from `I`.  But: note that if the *only* change we got from `I` was to this `somefile.ext`, *and* we resolved the problem by still-removing `somefile.ext`, there are now no changes to commit.  Running `git rebase --continue` will complain, and suggest that maybe we need to `git rebase --skip` to *drop* original commit `I` entirely.

Whichever is correct, we should do that (`--continue` and copy the *rest* of `I` to `I'`, or `skip` and toss out `I` entirely), giving:

```
          H--I   [abandoned]
         /
...--F--G--J--K   <-- origin/master
               \
                H'--I'  <-- master
```

or the same without `I'`.

In any case, we're now ready to `git push` again, the same as after merging.

Comment: A key detail here is that cherry-picking performs a merge which doesn't rely on a common ancestor. Picking I would use H as the ancestor, when the diffs are produced from this ancestor, "somefile.ext" can also report as being deleted by us if the file were introduced in H.

Comment: @cdosborn: right, the "ancestor" for cherry-pick is forced to be the parent of the to-be-picked commit. (If that's a root commit, Git uses an empty-tree commit, so that all files are added by both us and them.)