# Git: Add merge rule to config for specific file

Tags: git, configuration, git-merge

I am using git to track a large LaTeX document which I write using Kile on different machines.

Kile writes to its `.kilepr` config file when closing Kile. The problem I often run into is that I commit **before** closing Kile. So I commit and push, work on the other machine, and when I come back and want to pull I get a merge conflict because the `.kilepr` file contains the cursor position (which obviously changed now).

My question: Is there a way to add a merge rule to git config for a specific file (always use *--theirs*)? Using `.gitignore` is not an option since the `.kilepr` file contains important information such as files in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All possible ways to simulate a merge -s theirs are listed in "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912267/6309)".

But for one file, all you need is a merge driver, declared in a `.gitattributes` file, with a `keepTheir` script like:

```
mv -f $3 $2
exit 0
```

See "[“`git merge -s theirs`” needed — but I know it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist)" for a concrete example of a custom merge driver (including [my own version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910479/6309)).

Comment: @user334287 sure it will work: it is executed by the msys bash included with msysgit.

Answer (score 1):

2018 solution:  Merge Drivers

In git config you can add custom merge drivers:

```
[merge "my-custom-driver"]
    name = A custom merge driver used to resolve conflicts in certain files
    driver = my-merge-tool.sh %O %A %B
```

but you can also just return 'true' for the driver which will always keep local changes:

```
[merge "keep-local-changes"]
    name = A custom merge driver which always keeps the local changes
    driver = true
```

Then in .gitattributes you can define which file types use which custom merge drivers:

```
/folder/**/*.fileExtension merge=keep-local-changes
```