# Tell git to treat pbxproj as text

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I'm using Mapbox-ios-sdk and try to merge difference from the source in Github to my local hack.

Now I'm trying to tell Git to treat  pbxproj file as text by writing

```
*.pbxproj text -crlf -diff -merge union
```

to a new file ./git/info/attributes

On `git diff MapView/MapView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` it still treats it as binary:

```
diff --git a/MapView/MapView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/MapView/MapView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
index d91c5b9..d8d04df 100755
Binary files a/MapView/MapView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and b/MapView/MapView.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj differ
```

I've also tried to write it as .gitattributes but it still treat the file as binary. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man `gitattributes` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), `-crlf` and `-diff` seem to be associated with a way to make a file *as binary*.

So this should be closer to the mark (a bit like in [this config](https://github.com/cruppstahl/hamsterdb/pull/12/files)):

```
*.pbxproj text -merge union
```

Comment: I am not sure if the merging is proper though. Somehow I'm still not  incorporating the new files into the project file added from the remote repository.

Comment: @huggie does a diff between the local `pbxproj` and the remote ones clearly shows those extra files?

Comment: @huggie note: if there are conflicts, a simple script can help resolve them: https://gist.github.com/1790379

Comment: I don't know. I've gone ahead and just override my project file with the new one, since I didn't think I added any new files. Now it compiles just fine, though when I run my project image resources from the project is not found and it terminate on runtime. I posted another question for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913447/xcode-incorporating-a-project-but-resource-cannot-be-found

Comment: @huggie "just override my project file with the new one": Then a custom merge directive "`keepTheir`" would help here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1910479/6309