# git overwrite branch but keep history

Tags: git

I want to overwrite all the content in a development branch with another one (namely, master), but I don't want to miss the older commits on the dev branch.

This is what I want:

[image: what I want]

I tried both to [merge with ours strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch) and by [doing an hard reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git) but the dev branch keeps losing the older commits.

What I'm trying to obtain is a commit that has zero diff between blue and red, and the dropped code while diffing blue with the first black one.

---

Just to share an overview of the solutions tried until now.
By doing this:

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours dev
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

I obtain this (dev gets all the history from master)

[image: merge]

By doing this

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard master
```

I obtain this (if I push develop i will lose all the black commits):

[image: reset]

If i do this:

```
git checkout dev
git merge $(git commit-tree -p dev -m "Align master > dev" master^{tree})
```

I obtain this (almost perfect, yet I would be difficult to recall the exact moment when I did the trick):

[image]

Comment: just curious why putting past history on the dev branch this way? why not rebase?

Comment: he want to keep old history. rebase would discard it.

Comment: Rebase makes a lot of conflicts arise in the process (and having a whole lot of commits, I'm having a ton of conflicts. This is simply not practical). I imagined not to have any conflict because of a complete, blindfolded overwrite of everything in the dev branch.

Comment: If you use the ours strategy (`merge -s ours`) no history and no commits will be lost. All changes will be "lost" (i.e. overwritten) though. But that is exactly what you are asking. See also: [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/112968)

Comment: @knittl I tried both the -s ours and the -X theirs strategies (checking out respectively on the target and the source branches), but after those I still have differences between develop and master (namely, I have some never-deployed data on develop that I want to reset, but since merge is a non-destructive procedure this stuff continues to exist on develop).

Comment: @freshdevelop I would understand this for `-X` which is a strategy option for how to deal with conflicts. `-s` takes everything from one branch and nothing from the other. Should we continue this [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214272/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-61914439-git-overwrite-branch-but-keep-histor)?

Comment: What you want is the equivalent of `git merge -s theirs`, which does not exist—but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741538/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910444/1256452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can go like this:

```sh
git checkout -f develop # go to develop branch
git merge --no-commit master
git checkout master -- . # this checkouts code from master and doesn't switch branch
# you are still in merge process on branch develop
git commit
```

Note that tailing `-- .` changes behavior of `git checkout`.

Comment: Works well for keeping the old commits but then running `git diff dev..master` gives me non-empty results.

Comment: did you run this commands in root directory of repository? This `.` means current directory. If you were in sub-directory then not everything from `master` will be checkout.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that I'm running bash from the base folder. Still, diffing gives me results on files that does not seem to be changed at all in the "blue" commit.

Comment: That is interesting, that there is a problem with deleted files.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the previous comment about file removal. What I was saying, third instruction leaves behind file removals, that are not reported from master to develop. Doing `git rm $(git diff --name-only master -- .)` seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your needs correctly, you want to make a new commit on `dev` and the commit makes the content of `dev` exactly the same with `master`. If so,

```
git checkout dev
git merge $(git commit-tree -p dev -m "foo" master^{tree})
```

`git commit-tree` creates a commit from `master` head's tree, so that the new commit has the same content with `master`. The command returns the hash of the commit, which can be passed to `git merge`.

`-p dev` specifies `dev` head as the new commit's parent.

`-m "foo"` uses `foo` as the new commit's message. You can use literally `foo`, a random string, because in the end you can use `git commit --amend` to specify a formal message.

`master^{tree}` means the hash of the tree object of `master` head.

In this case `git merge` has the same effect with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Hey, this seems to work! Thanks!
Only thing is, what I'm getting is a new commit on develop that equals master (so diff is empty as expected) but there's not an explicit link between the branches (as I can see in my gui).