# git partial merge, not whole branch

Tags: git, merge

I've read about some tricks with merge in [Git: merging public and private branches while while keeping certain files intact in both branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807036/git-merging-public-and-private-branches-while-while-keeping-certain-files-intact) and others and not found a solution.

In my case I'm feeling need to do opposite merge strategy. In parallel development I have to keep some files same across the arbitrary branches. From other side I do not want to do squash or no-commit merge, while difference are significant and could break current state of testing branch.

What I want something like

`git checkout testing`

`git merge config.xml -b development` or `git merge config\*.xml -b development`

I guess this is like `git merge-files ...` command, but second file delivered from the branch, not from the filesystem.
Is it possible? or may be there is a kind of workaround? submodules? attributes?

Thanks

Comment: See also [How to do a partial merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527195/how-to-do-a-partial-merge-in-git)

Comment: Cherry picks will create a duplicate commit, and down the road that can cause excess merge conflicts, or worse yet, no conflicts and the wrong code is taken. @Vadzim comment is a link to the correct answer if you want to do true partial merges that will allow your branches to reconcile properly when cherry picked doppelgangers meet each other. This links to a 10 part blog post that you will probably have to read twice before it will make any sense, but well worth the time if you really want to understand git merging.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do.

One, you can *cherry-pick* the changes you want, which applies only a single commit. For example, if there's a change that only touches `config.xml`, you can cherry-pick it with

```
$ git cherry-pick $COMMIT_ID_YOU_WANT
```

You could also just grab `config.xml` from the development branch:

```
$ git checkout testing
$ git checkout development -- config.xml
```

That'll get you the same version of `config.xml` that exists in the development branch, but note that it won't pull in the history of changes to the file.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks. Only one more wish, it would luxury if I could write git cherry-pick $COMMIT_ID config.xml. Ok, this is a wish to the git forum.

Comment: For the second solution: Would this cause a merge conflict if the testing branch would be merged to the development branch? I have a situation where I want to bring the changes from one feature branch to an other, and I'm not so sure if that's a good idea because when both branches merged back to the master, it could cause a big havoc of conflicts...

Comment: is the -- in 
git checkout development -- config.xml
necessary?

Comment: @RobinReborn: No, it's only necessary if you also have a branch with the same name as the file, but I always add it by habit.

Answer (score 24):

If you just want to apply changes made by a certain range of commits (this can as well be only a single commit), made to only a subset of files then do:

```
git diff commit1..commit2 filepattern | git apply --index && git commit
```

You could also just apply the above pattern excluding `git commit`, review your staging area to see if all changes are as required and finally commit the staging area manually.

Comment: link not working

Comment: true, I have removed the referencing link now

Answer (score 14):

Here's a repository with a step-by-step documentation to clarify the dangers of partial merge and show the right way.

https://gitlab.com/bimlas/learning-by-testing-git-partial-merge/tree/doc

TL;DR:

Merge is has to be what it is: union of branches. If you doing a merge commit without merging all the files, and you will try to merge the same branches later, than Git thinks that you merged everything in the first merge commit, thus the earlier commits does not matter, it will skip the unmerged changes before the first merge.

Use `checkout` to copy files from one branch to another:

```
git checkout BRANCH -- FILE
git commit -m "Partial merge"
```

Comment: Just fixed the link.

Comment: What does the `--` mean?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian It's used to separate Git commands and arguments from list of files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321491/2520275

Comment: Just wondering about authorship issues here and other posts also. Would it possible to identify the original author of the changes made in that file later? If not it might be at least politically more correct to have a commit message like "Partial merge $FILENAME from commit $COMMIT_HASH and branch $BRANCH_NAME". :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to merge against a file directly picked from the git-tree.
What I suggest is to do something like :
`$ git ls-tree development -- config.xml

$ git show <blob-hash> > config.xml.development`

Then get the common base :

`$ git ls-tree $(git merge-base HEAD development) -- config.xml

$ git show <blob-hash> > config.xml.base`

And finally :

`$ git merge-file config.xml config.xml.base config.xml.development`

I did not test that, though.

With a shell like zsh, you can avoid saving the blob into a temporary file with this :

> `$ git merge-file config.xml =(git show <base-blob-hash>) =(git show <dev-blob-hash>)`

Comment: In bash, you could do:

`$ git merge-file config.xml $(git show <base-blob-hash>) $(git show <dev-blob-hash>)`