# Merging a subset of files to another git branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

In a git repository, there are two branches: `master` and `gh-pages` (which is used to publish static content on Github).

Suppose the repo, on `master` branch, has two directories `a` and `b`:

```
-- root
 |-- a
 |-- b
```

After switching to `gh-pages`, how can I run a merge such that *only* directory `b` will be merged with new content from `master` (and `a` ignored, given that it is not static content that should not be published)?

A simple `git merge master` is not enough since it always assumes `a` is new content that can be merged to `gh-pages`. Something more is needed, and I'm not sure what it is.

(Assume `gh-pages` was initially created with `git checkout --orphan`, or that it already has content only in directory `b` after a manual merge.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here [git partial merge, not whole branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315948/git-partial-merge-not-whole-branch)

Basically, you check out `gh-pages`, and then reset `a` to the HEAD of `master`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot cherry-pick comits that only add to folder b, you need [git checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)

```
git checkout gh-pages
git checkout master b
```