# Git - don't merge deletes

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I've a branch `develop` with files:

- index.php
- test.php

I'm creating branch `release` from it, where I set versions, make small bugfixes, etc, and **delete test.php** which doesn't go into production release. Then I want to merge this branch into `develop` but want to **keep test.php** in develop branch. How to do it? Default behaviour of `git merge` just deletes the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ I would rather **[rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178)** develop branch (if you haven't pushed it to a remote repo yet) on top of master, to make sure all my development is still compatible with the latest release (and all its bug-fixes).
If your current development is really different from release (massive refactoring), then and only then I would consider cherry-picking the bug-fixes.

2/ If a file needs to be kept as is during a merge, you can set a [merge manager in a `.gitattribute` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807036/git-merging-public-and-private-branches-while-while-keeping-certain-files-intact) only in the develop branch.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional wisdom is that you **never merge from a release branch into a development branch.**  Instead, apply the bugfixes commits to the development branch using `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: And then the deletion of test.php happens in its own commit, and that commit doesn't get cherry-picked?

Comment: Correct.  The bug fixes should all be represented in self-contained commits.  Then the specific commits that need to be backported to the development branch can be cherry-picked.

Comment: +1.  I would add: **write the bugfixes in the release branch** if you can.  Then, you can import the fixes into the development branch with `git merge`.

Comment: @EOL: Yes, that would definitely be the preferred way to do it.

Comment: I'm following branching model described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, so while techincally I can do cherry-pick I want to see actual branch merging in development history.

Comment: @galymzhan: That model does not include "production" branches, that is, branches that contain changes specific to a production environment.  **The moment you committed the deletion of `test.php`, you decided not to use the branching model described there.**

Comment: The model has definition of `release` branches. What model says:  "Release branches support preparation of a new production release. They allow for last-minute dotting of i’s and crossing t’s". So deletion of test.php is definitely a *preparation for production release* because leaving that file introduces security issue. On the other hand, it should be kept in develop branch, where it is used for testing purposes.

Comment: "Last-minute dotting of i's and crossing of t's" means "bumping version numbers, patching bugs, etc." It does not mean "removing files not meant for deployment."  `test.php` is part of the codebase -- if it needs to be removed, it should be by some install process, and this change *should not be committed.*  By committing the removal of this file, you give up any possibility of a clean merge back into the development branch.  `cherry-pick` and `rebase` are your only options at this point.