# Can I use git to track public and private branches that intentionally diverge?

Tags: git

Say I have:

```
           X         Z
o-----o----o-----o---o A
 \        /       \ /
  o------o---------o B
         Y
```

Suppose that A and B intentionally diverge, because (say) A is a public branch and B is a company-internal branch (which needs to have some differences for technical reasons and potentially has secrets that should not be in the open-source release).  Suppose X is a commit that intentionally does not pick up some of the changes in Y.

What is the best way to accomplish the following with Git?

1. Changes from Y that were intentionally omitted from the merge at X are not re-applied at Z.
2. I can publish a public version of A where the merge at X appears as a single squashed commit, so that none of the potentially secret information in Y (or other internal commits) shows up in the public revision history.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/999917/265575 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1807036/265575

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the diagram you've drawn is possible in a single Git repository (given your secrecy/etc constraints). The only similar approach I can think of that would accomplish what you want is to keep three branches: `public`, `private`, and `shared`. Commits in `shared` are merged into both `public` and `private` when they're finished. This will allow divergence across the public/private branches, without the worry about re-applying diffs, because the commits will have been actually merged and thus will be genuine ancestors that git won't try to re-apply.

You can probably meld this with your desired approach, if you prefer, by developing for a while in `private`, and then rebasing to tease it apart into `shared` and `private` parts. Then you can merge the shared part back into `private`, and into `public` at the same time. Then you have the eventual behavior I describe in my first paragraph, but can develop more or less like you were hoping to in your question.