# Git: permanently ignore a specific changeset (but not future changes)

Tags: git, ignore, changeset

I have a settings file that contains some settings that are environment/machine/developer specific and some settings that are globally applicable.  When I change the stuff that is developer specific, I don't want those changes to show up in git, but I do want the stuff that is global to be committed.

So, I'm looking for something like

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

where I can ignore a specific changeset, but...  when I edit the file again, git will see the *new* changes but not the ignored ones.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Because Git is snapshot based at its core, you can't ignore a changeset (difference of snapshots) within a commit sequence.

There are a few approaches to keeping such a changeset independent, mainly by having an independent branch and continuously rebasing those extras.

Comment: Google suggests trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999064/how-to-keep-public-and-private-versions-of-a-git-repo-in-sync. In addition you can use `git rebase --interactive` to keep bring your private branch forward every time you fetch/pull in the main branch development. Or `git cherry-pick` if it is a single squashed commit with your private bits. There is also a 'merging rebase' script in the msysgit tree commit 9424c7c which attempts to keep the msysgit 'tweaks' on top of git.git as each release rolls by.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the explanation.