# How can I preview many git -repos easily?

Tags: git

I have many git repos in different projects and I would like to see a more pigeon view about their developments. I currently just enter individual repos but there must be easier ways. I have used Flowdock in team working (with RSS) but it is not really what I want. I need some pigeon-view about the git reports in console without repeatedly entering every project. (I currently see pigeon-view in github/bitbucket but I would like to see it on console or something like thta.) How can I preview many git -repos easily?

**Trial 1: some summary?**

```
$ find . -iname ".git"     # find me all git -repos
...
$  find . -iname ".git"|wc # shows the amount of repos
     40      40     434
$ How can I execute here a command to preview the developments in each repo?
$ They may be related projects so it would be extremely useful to see where
$ things are going!
$ 
$ find . -iname ".git" -exec cd '{}' & cd .. & git log $PWD|head -n7 \; # err
$ Some tool to do this kind of erroneous things? 
$ (there is some small mistake but it is just sketching my idea about pigeon view)
$ (also some sort of graphical connection diagram between repos would be useful)
```

**Related questions but not about the tool I am looking for**

1. [Using git for a project with many, many repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223921/using-git-for-a-project-with-many-many-repos)
2. [Is anyone really using git super/subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996164/is-anyone-really-using-git-super-subprojects)
3. [Git: how to avoid repetitive committing with sub-sub-sub... Git -repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068119/avoid-repetitive-committing-with-sub-sub-sub-git-repos)

Answer (score 2):

Either make one repo with each of your repos as remotes and fetch from all then filter your `git log --all` -- or -- make one repo with multiple submodules of your repos and do a `git submodule foreach git log` or something similar.